# Cross domain issue with $.ajax() method while checking to see if a URL exists

Tags: jquery

I am using this code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://mysharepointsite.com/SitePages/Home.aspx',
    type: 'HEAD',
    error: function () {
        //file not exists 
        alert('not ok');
    },
    success: function () {
        //file exists 
        alert('ok');
    }
});
```

I am calling it from another domain, it is failing because of the cross-domain issue.  How can i overcome this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a proxy for the server to make the connection then make ajax calls to the proxy, but you can also use [James Padolsey's cross-domain ajax mod](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery/) which will use YUI in the background to handle the cross-domain requests, it's a drop-in replacement for jQuery's `.ajax()` method. it's on [github here](https://github.com/padolsey/jQuery-Plugins/tree/master/cross-domain-ajax/)